# Integrity checks for composer.json repositories with type=package

Tags: php, composer-php

I’d like to add PHP libraries that are not available via Packagist (at least not in official versions) to my project. Here’s an example of what I’m doing right now:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "fpdf/fpdf",
        "version": "1.81.0",
        "dist": {
          "type": "zip",
          "url": "http://www.fpdf.org/en/dl.php?v=181&f=zip"
        },
        "autoload": {
          "files": ["fpdf.php"]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "fpdf/fpdf": "1.81.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "secure-http": false
  }
}
```

Running `$ composer install` results in a `composer.lock` entry like this:

```
"packages": [
    {
        "name": "fpdf/fpdf",
        "version": "1.81.0",
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "http://www.fpdf.org/en/dl.php?v=181&f=zip",
            "reference": null,
            "shasum": null
        },
        "type": "library",
        "autoload": {
            "files": [
                "fpdf.php"
            ]
        }
    }
```

As far as I can tell, there is no data available that could be used to check the integrity of the zip file. (Am I missing something?)

Is there a way to specify a hash for the zip file that would be used by Composer when setting up the dependencies for the project? I’d like to make sure that the zip content hasn’t changed and can’t be tampered with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "fpdf/fpdf",
        "version": "1.81.0",
        "dist": {
          "type": "zip",
          "url": "http://www.fpdf.org/en/dl.php?v=181&f=zip",
          "shasum" :"f832b04a5158645330d29bdb7265652dbcb6e4c3"
        },
        "autoload": {
          "files": ["fpdf.php"]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "fpdf/fpdf": "1.81.0"
  },
  "config": {
    "secure-http": false
  }
}
```

you can add the shasum to repository settings if the shasum is different you will get an exception during composer install

Comment: This works. I finally found where the properties for `dist` are specified: [JSON Schema file for composer.json](https://getcomposer.org/schema.json) (search for `"dist"`). Note: When adding a shasum to an existing setup, it only gets taken into account the next time the corresponding package is updated/reinstalled. A quick and dirty fix would be to delete the `vendor` directory and run `composer install` again. Another idea is to change the version number of the package, run `composer update`, reset the version number, and run `composer update` again.